# Isolating/indexing/ranging through a list object tuple set

Tags: python, list, object, tuples, iteration

So basically I have a tuple set kind of like this.

```
tuple_set = [('name1', 'score'), ('name2', 'score'), ('name3', 'score')]
```

It basically is a specific list in a larger dictionary of names/scores. I need to isolate name1, name2 and name3 in something that I can iterate through like a list.

It also might work if I can range through it but I can't take the range of the list object/tupleset.

Also appending to a list like this won't work cause it will only put a list of name1s

```
a_list = []

for stuff in tuple_set:
    a_list.append(tuple_set[0][0])
```

output: `a_list = ["name1", "name1", "name1"]`

Does someone know the solution?

Comment: Look at what you’re appending. _I need to isolate name1, name2 and name3 in something that I can iterate through like a list._ I’m not sure I understand this correctly, can you elaborate?

Comment: Also I'm voting to close this as a typo, since the only issue is that you're constantly appending the same element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop never uses the iteration variable, it just adds the same element over and over. Actually use the loop variable (ideally via unpacking to useful variable names) and things work:

```
for name, score in tuple_set:
    a_list.append(name)
```

Or one-line it as a `list` comprehension:

```
a_list = [name for name, score in tuple_set]
```

Comment: Ah wow, I'm slow. Thanks buddy. Sometimes I don't think properly

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this by using the `zip` approach so something like this:

```
 print(list(list(zip(*tuple_set))[0]))
```

the `*` is used to unpack the arguments in the tuple_set specifically the first item i.e accessing `0` and getting just the `names` back

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

your code will work with a small change if you think that while you are iterating over your `tuple_list` you have access to each element, one by iteration, so over one iteration you can grab your first element from variable `stuff` which is the `name` you want:

```
a_list = []

for stuff in tuple_set:
    a_list.append(stuff[0])
```

maybe you got confused because you can use each element index to the job:

```
a_list = []

for index in range(tuple_set):
    a_list.append(tuple_set[index][0])
```

you can also unpack each element in other 2 (the name and the score) like @ShadowRanger was suggesting:

```
for name, score in tuple_set:
    a_list.append(name)
```

if you like the job to be done in one line you can use a list comprehension:

```
a_list = [s[0] for s in tuple_set]
```

or:

```
a_list = [n for n, _ in tuple_set]
```